# Obtain integers from list of mixed data types

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

I have a list with mixed data types (integers and tuples containing integers) that represent indicies of files in the list `files`.  I want to handle the tuples differently than the plain integers because I need to aggregate numbers calculated from each file.  If I loop over the list `ind` and check if the entry is a tuple and pass it to the function `find_fname`, why does it print out `None` after each entry? Here is a minimal working example:

```
def find_fname(ind, files):
    print files[ind]


files = ['file1','file2','file3','file4']

ind = [0,(1,2),3]

for thing in ind:
    #check to see if entry in list is tuple
    if hasattr(thing, '__iter__'):
        print find_fname(thing[0],files)
        print find_fname(thing[1],files)
    else:
        print find_fname(thing,files)
```

returns:

```
file1
None
file2
None
file3
None
file4
None
```

I would like to see `find_fname` return:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the function `find_fname` is `None` because you print the value instead of returning it. If a function doesn't return anything, it implicitly returns `None`.

What you should do is:

```
def find_fname(ind, files):
    return files[ind]
```

Comment: you cant print from within a function?

Comment: Yes you can, but you already are printing the returning value in your code like `print find_fname(...)` so you end up printing them twice.

Comment: ok, Thanks alot!